# Eliminate the irrationality in the denominator of the fraction, using polynomials

Tags: polynomials, irrational-numbers

Eliminate the irrationality in the denominator of the fraction, using polynomials:

$$\frac{1}{2+10^{1/3}-100^{1/3}}$$

Comment: Please write your question, using mathJax. Could the "using polynomials" be made more specific?

Comment: @ProfessorVector using Euclid's algorithm or according to Horner's scheme, as I understand it.

Comment: The minimal polynomial according to [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%282%2B10%5E%281%2F3%29-100%5E%281%2F3%29%29) is $22x^3+42x^2-6x+1$.

Comment: @Rohan I just found that out with PARI/GP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given number is equal to $$-\frac{14+8\cdot 10^{1/3}+3\cdot 100^{1/3}}{22}$$

Denote $x:=10^{1/3}$

Then, we have $$\frac{1}{2+x-x^2}=-\frac{1}{(x-2)(x+1)}=-\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{x-2}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{x+1}$$ $$=-\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{x^2+2x+4}{x^3-8}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{x^2-x+1}{x^3+1}$$

Now plug $x$ into the last expression to get the final result.

Comment: Sorry, but can a detailed solution?

Comment: And where did the fraction -(1/3) come from?

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition